# BuddyPress - User Login instead of Full Name

Tags: buddypress

Im trying to display user login instead of user full name below each post avatar. Im using the following hook:

```
function my_member_username_link() {

    global $post;

    if (isset($post->post_author)) {

      $user_info = get_userdata($post->post_author);

      return '<a href="/' . $user_info->user_login . '/" title="' . $user_info->user_login . '">' . $user_info->user_login . '</a>';      

    } 


}

add_filter('bp_core_get_userlink','my_member_username_link');
```

This works on each avatar close to each post, but acts weird in the right sidebar where my session is displayed.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working in the sidebar is likely because the sidebar content is *outside* the Loop, and `$post` data, and thus, `$post->post_author`, are only available *inside* the Loop.

You could try setting a variable equal to `$post->post_author` while still inside the Loop, and then passing that variable to `get_userdata()` in your function call outside the Loop.